# (400) Unknown metric(s): ga:socialNetwork'

Tags: php, api, google-analytics

I need get `acquisition->channels` info. I think I can get it using "`ga:socialNetwork`" dimension. But when I use it I get the following error:

```
(400) Unknown metric(s): ga:socialNetwork
```

However, `ga:socialNetwork` dimension exists: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

My service call:

```
$service->data_ga->get('ga:xxxxx', '2010-01-01', '2015-01-15', 'ga:socialNetwork', $optParams);
```

Comment: Just to get the obvious out of the way: The error message suggests you are trying to use ga:socialNetwork as a metric (not a dimension), so can you check this is not just a typo in your code ?

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff, I have edited my question adding my service call

Answer (score 3):

`ga:socialNetwork` is a `dimension` not a `metric`. You are attempting pass in a `dimension` to the parameter that expects a `metric`.

Attempt the following to correct your code:

```
$optParams = array(
    'dimensions' => 'ga:socialNetwork',
    'sort' => '-ga:sessions');

$service->data_ga->get(
  'ga:xxxxxx',
  '2010-01-01',
  '2010-01-15',
  'ga:sessions',
  $optParams);
```

`ga:sessions` is a metric where `ga:socialNetwork` is a dimension, this [help center article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033861?hl=en) should help clarify the difference.